# How do I calculate memory system latency (access time)?

Tags: hardware, computer-science, latency, cpu-architecture

I've been searching for some type of equation or explanation of how to find the latency (access time) of a memory system when given the bandwidth, the precharge (refreshing) time between accesses, and how many bytes of data are being transferred.

Also I am not sure as to how memory interleaving would change this latency.

---

I was able to find this latency formula:

```
latency = seek time + rotational delay + transfer time + controller delay
```

but apparently it's applies to hard drives, not system memory. Is there a formula for the latency of a system memory/what is it?

Comment: I was able to find this latency formula: latency = seek time + rotational delay + transfer time + controller delay but apparently it's applies to hard drives, not system memory... Is there a formula for the latency of a system memory/what is it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I'm on my cell phone, so it isn't easy to directly reference, but I think that the Wikipedia article on bandwidth has some good smidgens of knowledge.

From what I understand, bandwidth is along the lines of `bandwidth = frequency / latency x data rate x bus width`. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. I was able to find this latency formula:

latency = seek time + rotational delay + transfer time + controller delay

but apparently it's applies to hard drives, not system memory...

Is there a formula for the latency of a system memory/what is it?

Thanks again!

Comment: well going on with the concept of hard drives you can adapt it to system memory. since we know latency is the time we request the information until we get the information it would be latency = the time to address the memory (should be nigh instant) + time for the data bits to be placed onto the data bus. if you google memory latency it should explain better. and as an fyi the CAS latency specs on memory upgrades refer the the number of cycles required to put the data back on the data bus.

i.e. 9-9-9-24 at 1600MHz means for a typical fetch it takes 9 x 1/1600 million seconds to get the data